# Ruby - fastest way to select items that belong to two arrays by nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

My Ruby query is really slow. I'm looking for a faster way to select items that belong to two arrays

`listA` is a list of objectA with the attribute `name`

`listB` is a list of objectB with the attribute `name`

There can be multiple items in `listA` that all have the same `name`, but nothing in `listB` with the same `name`. There are also items in `listA` whose `name`s are not in `listB`. I want a function (loop) to return all the items in `listA` where their `name` is in `listB`.

This is my current solution, but it's too slow. How can I make it faster ?

```
z = 0
new = []
while z < listB.length 
    hold = listA.select{|obj| obj.name == listB[z].name}
    new += hold
    z += 1
end
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to maximise lookup speed. The best speed you can reach for lookup is O(1) using Hashes. My method described below is 1000x faster than your code and 350x faster than a loop with `include?` for `n=10000`

**EDIT 2** : [This link](https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/hash-lookup-in-ruby-why-is-it-so-fast) explains more in detail why hash lookup is fast.

```
names = {}
listB.each{|item| names[item.name] = true}
result = listA.select{|item| names[item.name]}
```

**EDIT** : Updates to the benchmark.

- 03/08/2015 - Added user12341234 set method

---

**Benchmark Code**

```
class MyObject
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def name
    @name
  end
end

n=10000
k=n/10

listA = (1..n).map{ MyObject.new(('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle[0,8].join)}
listB = listA.sample(k)
listB += (1..(n-k)).map{ MyObject.new(('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle[0,8].join)}

require 'benchmark'
require 'set'

Benchmark.bm do |x|
    x.report("Hash") do
        names = {}
        listB.each{|item| names[item.name] = true}
        result = listA.select{|item| names[item.name]}
    end

    x.report("OP's code") do
        z = 0
        new = []
        while z < listB.length 
            hold = listA.select{|obj| obj.name == listB[z].name}
            new += hold
            z += 1
        end
    end

    x.report("Include") do
      names = listB.map(&:name)
      listA.select{|obj| names.include?(obj.name) }
    end

    x.report("Set") do 
        names = listB.map(&:name).to_set
        listA.select{|item| names.include?(item.name)}
    end
end
```

---

**Benchmark**

Specs :

- Intel Core i7 920 @ 2.67 GHz
- 13 GB RAM
- Windows 8 x64
- Ruby 21 x64

Results :

```
Algorithm       user     system      total        real
Hash         0.015000   0.000000   0.015000 (  0.013002)
OP's code   26.053000   0.016000  26.069000 ( 26.161283)
Include      9.219000   0.000000   9.219000 (  9.244161)
Set          0.016000   0.000000   0.016000 (  0.013001)
```

Comment: What about `include`?)

Comment: Sorry, I win :P. Actually I believe `include?` is also using a Hash for fast lookup, however it's rebuilding it for every iteration of the loop, whereas my code keeps the same dictionnary.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
names = listB.map(&:name)
listA.select {|obj| names.inlude? obj.name }
```

Answer (score 1):

The natural way to express unordered, non-duplicated data is using a set. Try:

```
require 'set'
names = listB.map(&:name).to_set
listA.select{|item| names.include?(item.name)}
```

Using @Cyrill_DD's benchmarks, this performs comparably to the hash implementation:

```
       user     system      total        real
Set   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.012556)
Hash  0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.011330)
```